# How can I use Ajax Toolkit AutoComplete Extender to make AutoComplete textBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have tried this example

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete_simple.ashx

but it is not working in the demo or in my project

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you tried using a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd actually recommend moving towards using JQuery and webmethods. I've found that using the AJAX.NET library eventually paints you into a corner which is difficult to get out of. I've spent several years fighting with AJAX.NET and found that when I made the transition to JQuery and webmethods my life became 100% simpler.

There are lots of AutoComplete plugins that people have written which will use a backend webservice (asmx perhaps) to provide the data.